# How to add array to template-driven form in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have created form for editing Recipe.
User can edit these properties.
As you can see below that Recipe contains two ingredients. User can modify or delete them.

[image: Edit form for Recipe]

**Next step i would achive is adding new ingredient input field dynamically**.

Could you tell me how to do that from `@ViewChild('editForm') editForm;` ?

```
export interface IIngredient {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    amount: number;
}
```

recipe.edit.component.ts

```
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('editForm') editForm;
  recipe: IRecipe;
  photos: IPhoto[] = [];
  ingredients: IIngredient[] = [];
  uploader: FileUploader;
  hasBaseDropZoneOver = false;
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  
  currentMain: IPhoto;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private recipeService: RecipeService,
    private toastr: ToastrService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadRecipe(); 
  }

  loadRecipe() {
    this.recipeService.getRecipe(this.route.snapshot.params.id).subscribe(recipe => {
      this.recipe = recipe;
      this.initializeUploader();
    })
  }

  deleteIngredient(id: number) {
    this.recipeService.deleteIngredient(id).subscribe(() => {
      this.ingredients.splice(this.ingredients.findIndex(p => p.id === id), 1);
      this.toastr.success('Ingredient has been deleted');
      this.loadRecipe(); 
    }, error => {
      this.toastr.error('Deleting ingredient has failed')
    })
  }

  updateRecipe(id: number) {
    this.recipeService.editRecipe(id, this.recipe).subscribe(next => {
      this.toastr.success('Recipe updated successfully');
    }, error => {
      this.toastr.error(error);
    });
  }

}
```

What i've tried to achive that:
I have created these two methods

```
  createIngredient(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      amount: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  addIngredient(): void {
    const ingredients = this.editForm.get('ingredients') as FormArray;
    ingredients.push(this.createIngredient());
  }
```

and on

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadRecipe(); 
        this.editForm = this.fb.group({
          ingredients: this.fb.array([this.createIngredient()])
        })
      }
```

My html

```html
    <div class="container mt-4 border" *ngIf="recipe">
        <form #editForm="ngForm" id="editForm" (ngSubmit)="updateRecipe(recipe.id)" >
          <h5 class=" text-center mt-2">Recipe details:</h5>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
              <label for="recipe.name">Recipe name:</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="recipe.name">
            </div>
            <ng-container  *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients; let i = index">
    
            
              <div class="row mb-3" > 
                <div class="col-10 col-md-8">
                  <label for="ingredient.name">Ingredient {{i + 1}} name: </label>
                  <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ingredient.name}} " [(ngModel)]="ingredient.name"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                </div>
               <div class=" col-10 col-md-3">
                <label for="ingredient.amount">Amount: </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ingredient.amount}}" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.amount"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
               </div>
          
               <div class="col-5 col-md-1 align-self-end ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " (click)="deleteIngredient(ingredient.id)"><i
                  class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
               </div>
              </div>
              </ng-container>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addIngredient()">
                  New Ingredient
              </button>
               </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <br>
              <p>Add recipes</p>
            </div>
          <h5 class=" text-center mt-4">Description</h5>
            <angular-editor cols=100% rows="6" [placeholder]="'Your description'" [(ngModel)]="recipe.description"  name="description"></angular-editor>
        </form>  
        <button [disabled]="!editForm.dirty" form="editForm" class="btn btn-success btn-block mb-5 mt-5">Save changes</button>
      </div>
```

If user hits button on the console is following error:

```
recipe-edit.component.html:28 ERROR TypeError: this.editForm.get is not a function
```

@UPDATE

I achieved desired effect but i'm not sure if it's done properly.

Here is what i've done:

In html
from input i deleted [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ingredient.amount}}" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.amount">
```

Ingredient's properties changed into optional

```
export interface IIngredient {
    id?: number;
    name: string;
    amount?: number;
}
```

and in my component

```
  addIngredient(): void {
    this.recipe.ingredients.push({
      name: '',
      amount: 0
    });
  }
```

Now when i click "new ingredient" it creates new input field but when i delete value from value on the console i'm getting this error:

```
recipe-edit.component.html:14 ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
```

[image: ingredient input]

Comment: You have a ngFor in recipe.ingredients. You need to add to that array itself, e.g. `this.recipe.ingredients.push(*new ingredient*)`. Your take on create/add ingredient with form builder was in the direction of reactive forms, not template driven forms (you should not mix these two).

Comment: @GunnarB. thank you for your hints. I'm newbie in angular. Could you correct my code how to make it properly?

Comment: I don't use the template driven approach for forms, but apperently the name tag needs to be placed after the ngModel tag.

Comment: Could you please reproduce this issue on stackblitz.com?